# Restore failed for server xxxx/SQLExpress

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am using this code to restore a SQL Server database

```
Server databaseServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(CvVariables.SQL_SERVER_NAME));
string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,);
string databasePath = @"D:\cvdb.bak";

Restore databaseRestore = new Restore();
databaseRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
databaseRestore.Database = CvVariables.Catalog;
databaseRestore.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(databasePath, DeviceType.File));
databaseRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
databaseRestore.SqlRestore(databaseServer);
```

I am using SQL Server code-named 'Denali' Express Core (CTP 3).

This code works fine on the developer PC but on the client's pc, it throws this exception:

> Restore failed for server xxxx/SQLExpress

I don't understand where I am wrong.

InnerException Is :

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Cafeteria_Vernier_db.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). 
File 'Cafeteria_Vernier_db' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Cafeteria_Vernier_db.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. 
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Cafeteria_Vernier_db_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). 
File 'Cafeteria_Vernier_db_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Cafeteria_Vernier_db_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. 
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details. 
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException) 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType) 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType) 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType) 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries) 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries) 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
```

Comment: Are the servers the same version. SQL Server don't like to restore a backup from a newer SQL Server version. There is usually more information in the information message. Can you restore the backup on the server from Management Studio?

Comment: Yes both are same version and yes i store the backup on the server from Management Studio.

Comment: Do you get any further information in the exception, status codes, inner exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the paths on your target machine are different from the corresponding paths on the original backup machine.

SUGGESTION:
I'd forgot about the .Net API stuff and drop directly down to T-SQL (you can do this from C#, of course).

Your new T-SQL script will look something like this:

```
-- REFERENCE: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=147723
RESTORE DATABASE paintcheck
FROM DISK = 'C:\paintcheck.BAK'
WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'paintcheck' TO 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\paintcheck_Data.MDF',
MOVE 'paintcheck_log' TO 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\paintcheck_Log.LDF'
```

Here are some more examples:

http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2011/07/11/146167.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

'Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to relocate the database files by using the following code:

```
Server databaseServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(CvVariables.SQL_SERVER_NAME));
string databasePath = @"D:\cvdb.bak";

// Generate new FilePath for both Files.
string fileMdf = System.IO.Path.Combine(databaseServer.MasterDBPath, "Cafeteria_Vernier_db.mdf");
string fileLdf = System.IO.Path.Combine(databaseServer.MasterDBLogPath, "Cafeteria_Vernier_db_log.ldf");
RelocateFile relocateMdf = new RelocateFile("Cafeteria_Vernier_db", fileMdf);
RelocateFile relocateLdf = new RelocateFile("Cafeteria_Vernier_db_log", fileLdf);

Restore databaseRestore = new Restore();
databaseRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
databaseRestore.Database = CvVariables.Catalog;
databaseRestore.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(databasePath, DeviceType.File));
databaseRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateMdf);
databaseRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateLdf);
databaseRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
databaseRestore.SqlRestore(databaseServer);
```